# Visual Studio 2017 for Mac - MonoDevelop extension could not be started

Tags: monodevelop, visual-studio-mac

Launching a clean-installed Visual Studio 2017 for Mac, I get the following error dialog:

[image]

```
The following extensions could not be started:
MonoDevelop
Full Path: MonoDevelop.Ide

Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

The IDE log goes as following:

```
(Beginning of file)
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:38Z]: Starting Visual Studio 2017 for Mac 7.0.1 (build 24)
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:38Z]: Running on Mono 5.0.1.1 (2017-02/5077205) (64-bit)
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:38Z]: Operating System: Mac OS X 10.12.6
Darwin 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0
    Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017
    root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:38Z]: GTK: Using gtkrc from /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/gtkrc.mac-dark
Could not find `PresentationCore` referenced by assembly `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.UI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`.
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:42Z]: Accessibility disabled
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:42Z]: Using GTK+ 2.24.23
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:42Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Core
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:42Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Ide
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.MacPlatform
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Initializing Runtime Mono 5.0.1.1
Starting Visual Studio
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.TextTemplating
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xml
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AspNet
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.UnitTesting
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Refactoring
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.CSharpBinding
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.GtkCore
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.PackageManagement
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger.VsCodeDebugProtocol
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DotNetCore
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.Ide.Insights
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xamarin.Ide
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xamarin.Ide.Mac
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.MacDev
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.TestCloud
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.IPhone
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.MonoAndroid
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VBBinding
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.Forms.Addin
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.WebToolingAddin
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Unity
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: .NET Core SDK not found.
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: .NET Core runtime not found.
ERROR [2017-08-07 17:31:43Z]: Add-in error (MonoDevelop.Ide): 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.MicrosoftTemplateEngineProjectTemplatingProvider' threw an exception. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/Volumes/Storage (macOS)/ryo/.templateengine" is denied.
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x0005f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:121 
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x0008f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:85 
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/DirectoryInfo.cs:144 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo:Create ()
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00030] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:103 
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x0008f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:85 
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/DirectoryInfo.cs:144 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo:Create ()
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00030] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:103 
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x0008f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:85 
  at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Utils.PhysicalFileSystem.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00000] in <a2504912b6304074a04ad39fc0858504>:0 
  at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Paths.WriteAllText (System.String path, System.String value) [0x00020] in <5a88eac832b84150b64662534e9b54e6>:0 
  at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.Save () [0x00028] in <5a88eac832b84150b64662534e9b54e6>:0 
  at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.ComponentManager.Register (System.Type type) [0x001ac] in <5a88eac832b84150b64662534e9b54e6>:0 
  at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.ComponentManager..ctor (Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Abstractions.ISettingsLoader loader, Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsStore userSettings) [0x001e8] in <5a88eac832b84150b64662534e9b54e6>:0 
  at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.EnsureLoaded () [0x000f9] in <5a88eac832b84150b64662534e9b54e6>:0 
  at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.TryGetMountPointInfoFromPlace (System.String mountPointPlace, Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Abstractions.Mount.MountPointInfo& info) [0x00000] in <5a88eac832b84150b64662534e9b54e6>:0 
  at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.TryGetMountPointFromPlace (System.String mountPointPlace, Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Abstractions.Mount.IMountPoint& mountPoint) [0x00000] in <5a88eac832b84150b64662534e9b54e6>:0 
  at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.TemplateCache.Scan (System.String templateDir) [0x000d1] in <5a88eac832b84150b64662534e9b54e6>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.MicrosoftTemplateEngineProjectTemplatingProvider.UpdateCache () [0x0006f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/MicrosoftTemplateEngineProjectTemplatingProvider.cs:82 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.MicrosoftTemplateEngineProjectTemplatingProvider..cctor () [0x0007e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/MicrosoftTemplateEngineProjectTemplatingProvider.cs:65 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x0000f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:667 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x000a8] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:179 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00009] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:153 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00027] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5639 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00039] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:201 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:134 
  at Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode.CreateInstance () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/TypeExtensionNode.cs:93 
  at Mono.Addins.InstanceExtensionNode.GetInstance () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/InstanceExtensionNode.cs:73 
  at Mono.Addins.ExtensionNodeEventArgs.get_ExtensionObject () [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/ExtensionContext.cs:1330 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.TemplatingService.OnTemplatingProvidersChanged (System.Object sender, Mono.Addins.ExtensionNodeEventArgs args) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/TemplatingService.cs:70 
  at Mono.Addins.ExtensionNode.add_ExtensionNodeChanged (Mono.Addins.ExtensionNodeEventHandler value) [0x00021] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4693/7ab1ca2c/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/ExtensionNode.cs:172 
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:44Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.MonoMac
INFO [2017-08-07 17:31:44Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Packaging.
....
```

By clicking "Yes" in the dialog, I can actually proceed to the editor, but the compiler has some issues: core classes not defined/implemented etc.

I am using Sierra 10.12.6 and Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac 7.0.1 (build 24).

Comment: Is there any more information in the IDE log? (Help - Open Log Directory). The MonoDevelop.Ide extension is a core part of the IDE so if that is not running a lot of other things will not work.

Comment: @MattWard, I pasted the log in my question. Thank you for your help

Comment: Sounds like a config file cannot be saved. But it is pretty deep a track to go, https://github.com/dotnet/templating/blob/rel/2.1.0-preview1/src/Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge/Settings/SettingsLoader.cs#L49 Not even know where the file is yet.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the exact line of code. It's hard for me to follow the reference on GitHub. Where can I submit this issue?

Comment: @RyoichiroOka post to the repo I linked first to learn where the file is saved, and then you can try to remove the file on your Mac and see whether it solves the issue.

Comment: The .NET Core templating engine will try to create some files under your user profile. On my machine there are files in the directory `~/.templatingengine/Visual Studio/7.0/`. This is under my user profile so it is in `/Users/UserName/.templatingengine/Visual Studio/7.0/`. Your IDE log output has your user profile on a different volume: `/Volumes/Storage (macOS)/ryo/.templateengine`. The file being saved looks to be the settings.json file. As Lex suggested I would check the permissions here and see if a file can be created inside the `.templatingengine/Visual Studio/7.0/` directory.

Comment: @MattWard twas the permission. Solved it by allowing read/write to the drive for every user. Thank you for your help. Lex - great thanks to you too.

Comment: From Sierra onwards mac OS X has added functionality to prevent downloaded apps from modifying files on the local system, unless that app has been moved from the download folder to somewhere like ./Applications and the end-user has ok'd this. Unless you do this, Sierra will run the application randomised directory with very limited permissions. Is this a possible cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was the user profile being saved without given a write permission in the saved location. Solved it by allowing read/write to the location for every user.

Comment: I ran visual studio with sudo once and it has caused a ton of problems, including this one. Did you do that as well?

Comment: @BWG I'm afraid but I don't remember. I was noob at mac back then. The apparent cause of my case was that I had put the settings file in a drive that is formatted in exFAT32, where that format made mac assign a weird permission to the file, which caused VS to fail reading the file.

Comment: Yeah I just started using mac and I fixed the problem by deleting and recreating my mac account.